# How to catch error in node mySQL queries?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use nodejs and mysql for my app. I do the DB query in such manner:

```
try {
    myDB.query(SQL, object, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        ...
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
}
```

But this is do not work because of async `query` func. So how to catch those errors, which is can occur in callback? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `throw` inside of async code with callbacks. You *must* use async error handling:

```
function makeQuery(callback) {
  myDB.query(SQL, object, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err)

      return
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

It's up to the caller to provide a suitable callback function that takes `(err, response)` or something similar. It's also the responsibility of the caller to intercept, handle, or forward any and all errors.

If you use Promise-driven code you can either use `.catch()` or `async` functions with `await` that will work inside `try`. [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) is a good Promise-driven database driver.

Then you have code that looks like this:

```
let result = await myDB.query(SQL, object)
```

Which is obviously a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this example:

```
try {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM ??',[Table], function (err) {
    if (err) console.error('err from callback: ' + err.stack);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error('err thrown: ' + err.stack);
}
```

for example. if "Table" does not exist, you would have the response:

```
'Table' doesn't exist
```

EDIT:

what @tadman says is correct, `if you use if (err) throw err`, you are only generating an exception error and you lose what you need.